# Node + Express: does not invoke callback after posting data to database

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js, and is using Express and Sequelize to build a restful api. For now I just need to create a user by the following code:

```
router.post('/preregister', function(req, res, next) {
    models.users.create(req.body, function(err, user) {
        console.log('req: ' + req.body);
        if (err) res.json(err);
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

The system output the sql statement, and I can see that the data is created by querying database, but then the server hangs there and does not do anything any more, not even printing out the 'req' line right before the if statement, which looks like the function(err, user) part is never touched. Looks like something fundamental is wrong. But what is missing??

### EDIT

The users model is defined as below:

```
"use restrict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
    var users = sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            isUnique: true,
            field: 'id' 
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            isUnique: true,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            },
            field: 'email'
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    return users;
};
```

Comment: please try console.log(err) before your if statement. And I think the problem is that in case of error, you are not sending response back. You are sending response in case of success only but not in case of error. So first, try to console.log(err), if it prints means your callback is getting invoked. Then do res.json(err) in case of error also, then your sever won't hang

Comment: @Abie unfortunately the res.json(err) doesn't output anything - looks like callback is not getting invoked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize uses (a modified version of) the [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) promises library, which means that this should work:

```
router.post('/preregister', function(req, res) {
  models.users.create(req.body).then(function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Sequelize` is Using `Promises` in it's latest versions

```
router.post('/preregister', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = models.users.build(req.body);
        user.save()
        .complete(function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(user);
        });
});
```

Comment: looks like what you provided gives 'undefined is not a function' after I removed the semi-column after build(req.body) - FYI I am using sequelize 3.5.1.

Comment: Check the edit i forgot to call the model `user.save()`

Comment: hmm, still gives a 500 status code and the 'undefined is not a function' thing.. Do I need to use any other require other than 'express' and '../models' ?

Comment: please tell me which function is undefined (which line of code),
and please make sure that your defining the models right

`var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT
 })`

Comment: Hi hussam, I just updated the OP with the users model. The error stacktrace does not specify which line gives the exception, so I don't know how to tell - the returned result is:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>undefined is not a function</h1>
            <h2></h2>
            <pre></pre>
        </body>
    </html>
and it is from the default error.jade. From the server log, it is saying:
POST /users/preregister 500 415.619 ms - 178 
and this is all I have..

Comment: @jamesdeath123 try this: `models.users.create(req.body).then(function(user) { ... }).catch(function(err) { ... })`

Comment: @robertklep that is it! If you could post your solution I could accept it!

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/preregister', function(req, res, next) {
    models.users.create(req.body, function(err, user) {
        if (err) res.json(err);
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately the res.json(err) doesnt even get invoked, as the server still hangs but nothing is output. I tried console.log(err) before the if statement but that doesn't even get printed out as well.

Comment: Just for debugging use `console.log(user);console.log(req.body);` before if condition. Comment the output

Comment: Hi Mahesh, I did put the console.log lines before the if statement, but they didn't output anything, which makes me believe the callback is not invoked..